# Copying text from multiple rows to another sheet using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

The code is based on a YouTube video 'IF Cell Contains Text Then Copy to Another Sheet | Copy Cell Based on Condition.'

It worked the first few times. As I added data it began to show only a few numbers from the list.

1. Data
   [image: Data]
2. Intended Sheet to move the data to
   [image: Intended Sheet to move the data to]
3. Code
   [image: Code Used]
4. Result
   [image: Result]

```vb
Sub CopyShipmentRecords()
    
    Dim StatusCol As Range
    Dim Status As Range
    Dim PasteCell As Range
    
    Set StatusCol = Sheet1.Range("E2:E22")
    
    For Each Status In StatusCol
        If Sheet5.Range("C2") = "" Then
            Set PasteCell = Sheet5.Range("C2")
        Else
            Set PasteCell = Sheet1.Range("C1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)
        End If
        If Status = "shipment oi" Then Status.Offset(0, -2).Resize(1, 5).Copy PasteCell
    
    Next Status
            
End Sub
```

Comment: `Set StatusCol = Sheet1.Range("E2:E22")` - it is only E2:E22 you're looking in, is this intentional? any data outside of that range won't get checked.

Comment: It looks like the reason you're being limited in what is copied over is that you're only checking cell C2  in your for loop and after the first copy and paste the logic goes to the else statement always only repasting information to the data sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing line 13 under the else statement from:

```
Set PasteCell = Sheet1.Range("C1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)
```

to

```
Set PasteCell = Sheet5.Range("C1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)
```